# How do I export a Pytorch model from Huggingface into ONNX with tokenizer included?

Tags: google-bigquery, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, onnx

I'm trying to convert a huggingface model into ONNX so I can use it in BigQuery ML. The latter one allows importing ONNX models. However transformers `tokenizer` is never included into the model.

How do I export a model WITH tokenizer into a single ONNX file?

Here's what I tried:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import sys
# model_name is being passed in from the command line
model_name = sys.argv[1]

# Load tokenizer and PyTorch weights form the Hub
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
pt_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)

# replace slashes with underscores
model_name_underscored = model_name.replace("/", "_")
# Save to disk
tokenizer.save_pretrained(model_name_underscored)
pt_model.save_pretrained(model_name_underscored)
```

And then

```
python3 -m transformers.onnx --model=./$model_name_underscored ${model_name_underscored}_onnx/
```

After importing it to BigQuery ML I can see that the model expects tokenized input, not a plain text.

Alternatively, how do I use AutoTokenizer within BigQuery ML so that the output of the model would be identical to the one Python script produces?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
dummy_model_input = tokenizer("Just a sample", return_tensors="pt")

torch.onnx.export(
    model,
    tuple(dummy_model_input.values()),
    f="model.onnx",
    input_names=['input_ids', 'attention_mask'],
    output_names=['logits'],
    dynamic_axes={'input_ids': {0: 'batch_size', 1: 'sequence'},
                  'attention_mask': {0: 'batch_size', 1: 'sequence'},
                  'logits': {0: 'batch_size', 1: 'sequence'}},
    do_constant_folding=True,
    opset_version=13,
)
```

Or give a look to `transformers.onnx` package in [Optimum](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/serialization#exporting-a-model-to-onnx%5D),

Comment: there seem to be no such argument as input_module in this method or anywhere in pytorch library.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: what you are trying to achieve might be impossible.

Long answer:

Depending on the exact tokenizer you are using, you might be able to produce a single onnx file using [onnxruntime-extensions library](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-extensions). However, this is unlikely to solve your problem. The thing is that the [ONNX standard](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md) does not include any operators for string manipulation which makes tokenization impossible. While onnxruntime-extensions provides the missing operators via [Custom Ops API](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/operators/add-custom-op.html), most likely these operators are not part of the runtime used by BigQuery, so it won’t be able to consume such a model.

Therefore, using a model with custom operators in BigQuery is a bigger challenge than creating such a model. You could still try though.

Answer (score -2):

You need to make sure that both the model and tokenizer are exported. Here's the way to export a Hugging Face model into a single ONNX file along with the tokenizer

```
import torch
import onnx
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

# Load the model and the tokenizer
model_name = "your-model-name"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Convert the model and the tokenizer to ONNX
dummy_input = tokenizer("dummy input", return_tensors="pt")
output = model(**dummy_input)
torch.onnx.export(model, tuple(dummy_input.values()), "model.onnx",
                  opset_version=12, input_names=["input"], output_names=["output"],
                  dynamic_axes={"input": {0: "batch_size"}, "output": {0: "batch_size"}})
tokenizer.save_pretrained("model.onnx")
```

This will save the model and the tokenizer in a single ONNX file named "model.onnx".

You can use the `TRANSFORM` clause in BigQuery ML to apply the tokenizer to your input data.

```
CREATE MODEL my_model
TRANSFORM(
  input_text,
  (SELECT input_ids FROM UNNEST(my_tokenizer_func([input_text]))) AS input_ids
)
OPTIONS(
  model_type='tensorflow',
  input_label_cols=['input_text'],
  output_label_cols=['input_ids'],
  model_path='gs://my-bucket/model.onnx'
)
AS
SELECT input_text, label FROM my_table;
```